# Palavra "pontos" deveria ser "votos" em se tratando de medalhas de tag

Tags: novo-recurso, status-aceito

Olhando os gráficos de pontuação para se obter medalhas de tag, notei o uso da palavra "pontos", em referência ao que precisa ser feito para obtê-las:

<kbd>[image: grafico de metas]</kbd>

Ocorre que se tratam de votos, e não pontos, pelo que pude perceber. Ou seja, se lá diz que faltam 100 pontos, na verdade faltam 100 votos, o que dá 1000 pontos.

O mesmo acontece na listagem de tags:

<kbd>[image: listagem de tags]</kbd>

Neste segundo caso, eu obtive muito mais que 152 pontos de reputação nesta tag (10x mais, tirando eventuais bonificações). Mas 152 exatos **votos** é o que eu tenho nesta tag :)

Alguém poderia dizer que "estes pontos não são pontos de reputação, mas sim pontos de tag". Fica pior ainda, acabamos inventando um nome novo para uma coisa que ja tinha nome (o voto). Prefiro achar que foi um problema de contexto na tradução apenas, pois no SOen trata-se de *score*.

Assim, concluo que seria bem menos confuso se utilizássemos as palavras "votos" e "votação" nestas duas situações, respectivamente, e adotar a mesma terminologia em eventuais situações análogas.

UPDATE: Quando me referi a votos, estava realmente pensando no saldo da votação (positivos - negativos), mas como o @Gabe ♦ apontou, isto pode realmente gerar outra confusão, pois 3 positivos - 2 negativos são de fato 5 votos, mas o que vale é o saldo (no exemplo dado, seria 1), e simplesmente chamando de "votos" não deixaria isto claro. Então, se alguém conseguir pensar em termos melhores que resolvam o problemas, seja bem-vindo a se manifestar.

Comment: Sim concordo (até mesmo no SOen encontrei algumas confusões de texto sobre votos e pontos). Acho que tem mais lugares que usam o termo errado.

Answer (score 8):

Enquanto eu avaliava o Transifex pra ver o que precisava traduzir, eu descobri o motivo de usar *pontos* ao invés de *votos*.

*Pontos* é a pontação da pergunta - `upvotes - downvotes` - e é o valor usado para calcular quão próximo você está de conseguir a medalha.

Isso pode ser observado, por exemplo, na [lista de respostas do @Bacco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:70%20[vb.net]) sobre [vb.net](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb.net).

<kbd>[image: Lista de respostas]</kbd>

[Uma delas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/46623) tem 2 votos a favor e 1 contra, com *pontuação* de 1.

<kbd>[image: Pergunta com voto contra]</kbd>

E é esse valor que é usado para calcular seu progresso [na tag](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/70/bacco?tab=tags&sort=votes&page=3).

<kbd>[image: progresso na tag]</kbd>

---

Então, não é possível traduzir *score* como "votos". Concordo plenamente que há uma confusão que seria bom resolver, mas infelizmente o uso direto de "votos" é ainda mais confuso...

Alguma ideia?

Comment: Talvez o problema seja o uso de "rep points" em outros lugares, na verdade. Só para eu entender, o problema de usar a palavra "votos" seria o fato de o mesmo identificador da palavra ser usada em mais contextos, ou você está se referindo à nomenclatura mesmo?

Comment: @Bacco O problema é que a medalha é concedida com base na pontuação total acumulada dos seus posts, não no número de *votos*. Então usar "votos" não é a melhor alternativa, já que causaria ainda mais confusão.

Comment: Placar seria uma tradução ao pé da letra, porém feia. Entendi que o score é a "soma dos votos positivos, menos os votos negativos", precisamos ver se tem algum nome não-ambíguo pra isso em português, sem ser pontos.

Comment: @Bacco Pois é... é uma sinuca que temos pelo uso mais indiscriminado de "pontos" como sinônimo de "reputação" aqui no SOpt.

Comment: bom, se eu conseguir pensar em algo comento. Vamos ver se alguém aparece com alguma idéia melhor

Comment: Talvez dê pra "liberar" a palavra "pontos" pra significar só *score* (e não rep). No Transifex pode ser trabalhoso, mas é possível. Agora, se muita gente já costuma usar "pontos" para reputação – no chat, por exemplo –, já fica mais complicado convencer todo mundo. cc @Bacco

Comment: @bfavaretto eu acho que em médio longo prazo sua solução funciona, e do mesmo jeito que temos que o "SO não é um fórum" no meta, podemos por um tipo de "reputação não são pontos". De qualquer forma, é bom o pessoal que está acostumado com o material do transifex dar uma pensada com carinho, pra não criarmos um problema pior. Esse tipo de coisa não precisa de pressa mesmo.

Comment: @Gabe me ocorreu que para "pontuação" poderia ser algo na linha de "saldo de votos", pelo tamanho. Não que seja essa palavra, só coloquei aqui pra dar mais o que pensar..

Comment: @Bacco Me parece bastante razoável...

Comment: @Gabe o problema é que eu não achei o "parzinho" de saldo de votos pro caso do gráfico.

Comment: @Bacco Como assim? (E pensei durante o almoço que talvez "saldo" já seja suficiente. Seria uma maneira de atribuirmos um novo termo a um "novo" conceito)

Comment: @Gabe quis dizer que "1/100 saldo" me soou meio estranho (no grafico), agora, "saldo de votos de +152" ja fica melhor (na tooltip).

Comment: @Bacco Ah, sim... Faz sentido. Mas o que eu vinha pensando é que talvez só seja sem sentido até todo mundo se habituar, e a gente pode criar um novo "termo". Assim como "pontos" é automaticamente associado à reputação. Haveria um período de adaptação, mas depois tudo ficaria numa boa

Comment: Pensando friamente, saldo é menos confuso que pontos, mas talvez com um pouco mais de tempo com todo mundo pensando, capaz que saia algo melhor. Sugiro deixar o saldo como "plano B" por enquanto.

Comment: @Gabe o que é sinuca?

Comment: @JorgeB. Vide o ítem "sinuca" mesmo, na lista. Tanto é o nome do jogo, quanto de uma situação de dificuldade no jogo: http://www.pontodasinuca.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=21:glosso-de-termos-usados-na-sinuca&catid=13:regras&Itemid=100034