# Pontuação de tags errada

Tags: bug, status-intencional, tags

Após ver [essa pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4943/20615), eu fiquei curioso em saber minha pontuação de cada tag. Até aí normal. Mas ao seguir os passos, eu vi que há certos lugares que a pontuação não "bate", ou seja, mostra números diferentes.

Ao ver o andamento para conseguir alguma medalha em específico mostra um valor, e ao ver em outros lugares, mostra outro. Confuso? rsrsrs

Talvez essas imagens ajudem a explicar.

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Podemos ver que na parte de acompanhar a próxima TAG temos um número de pontos, neste caso 91, e nos demais locais, temos outro, no caso 92.

Porém, se eu clicar para configurar outra TAG, o valor fica certo, como na imagem abaixo:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Para desencargo de consciência, eu fiz [essa query](http://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/452392/meus-votos-pontos-por-tas) no data.se (levando em consideração [esta resposta do @Gabe](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4646/20615)) para verificar os pontos(lembrando que reconheço o delay que tem em relação ao data.se) e o resultado pode ser visto na imagem abaixo:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Comment: Minha tentação é rejeitar por usar quadrados vermelhos ao invés de círculos à mão...

Comment: @Gabe É que a caneta acabou a tinta. Mas se quiser mandar uma do SO eu aceito. :p

Comment: @Gabe Aproveitando que comentou, poderia responder se isso é um BUG ou se é para ser assim mesmo?

Comment: Minha reação inicial é botar a culpa no cache, mas não olhei à fundo ainda pra saber direito. Preciso de um dev pra isso, mas vai ser difícil conseguir uma resposta hoje

Comment: **Off-topic:** Fui testar agora a medalha ouro pra tag PHP, perfil me diz em ambos locais que tenho 571 pontos, mas a query que o @DiegoF citou fala que tenho 575 pontos, todavia suponho que seja um erro na query. No entanto todas tags que testei no perfil e no próxima medalha estavam ok. Só pra resumir a query não parece funcionar bem então não podemos tirar conclusões usando ela infelizmente. Eu acho que ele conte os pontos de perguntas removidas (suposição).

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Então, temos isso, o delay e pode ser que tenha mais alguma coisa influenciando o que não da para ter certeza com o Data.SE. O mais estranho, é que só a [tag:javascript] está com esse erro.

Comment: A sim por isso marquei como off-topic, no caso a tag javascript esperada no meu é a prata e também esta ok, só queria mesmo afirmar que a query usada no data.se me parece estar errada pra quem ler não misturar ambos assuntos. Eu estava tentando entender o data.se pra ver se é possivel corrigir (se for mesmo uma falha na query) =)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Sim, eu entendi. :p.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Então, eu fiz uma adaptação dela ([essa](http://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/452392/meus-votos-pontos-por-tas)), mas ainda não consegui averiguar se está errada.

Answer (score 5):

Para ganhar a medalha você precisa ter votos suficientes em respostas. O placar que mostra junto da *tag* na lista delas mostra a quantidade de votos existentes em respostas e nas perguntas também (que não conta para a medalha).

Ajuda ter alguns truques. Em alguns casos dar uma olhada na própria *tag* pelos principais usuários pode te mostrar a real votação obtida por você nas respostas dela.

Fora isto tem a questão da atualização do banco de dados retardada (sem falar no cache que pode ser atualizado em certas operações ou por tempo). Então dependendo de onde está olhando pode estar mostrando um número defasado.

Então isto é *by design*. Pode ver:

[image: Bug Feature By design]

Comment: Acho que não me expressei bem. Me referia a mostrar 91 em um lugar e 91 em outro. Vou tentar ser mais claro.

Comment: Então, meu ponto é justamente o do seu último parágrafo. O sistema não ser atualizado em tempo real, somente em um lugar, não se enquadraria em "BUG"?

Comment: De maneira alguma. No máximo como experiência ruim para o usuário. É *by design* ainda que isto seja (ab)usado para explicar preguiça ou decisões pragmáticas/ideológicas que não colaboram com a experiência.